# How to add multiple formatter on JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

For the last value of ColModel, only the last NAME: is displayed, is there a way to display all the NAME: ? Appreciate your help. thanks

```
colModel: [
                   {
                       name: 'PRIORITY_CD', index: 'PRIORITY_CD', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true,

                   },
                   {
                       name: 'CODE_COMBI', index: 'CODE_COMBI', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true


                   },
                    {
                        name: 'ACTION', index: 'PRIORITY_CD', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true, formatter: detailsLink,
                        name: 'ACTION', index: 'PRIORITY_CD', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true, formatter: editLink,
                        name: 'ACTION', index: 'PRIORITY_CD', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true, formatter: deleteLink

                    },

               ]



function detailsLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
return "<a href=''../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/GetCritCombiMap'" + rowdata.PRIORITY_CD + " > Details</a>";


function editLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
return "<a href=''../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/GetCritCombiMap'" + rowdata.PRIORITY_CD + " > Edit</a>";


function deleteLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
return "<a href=''../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/GetCritCombiMap'" + rowdata.PRIORITY_CD + " > Delete</a>";
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you define the colModel in not correct. To do what you want you can have one field in colModel and one formatter with three links like this:

```
colModel: [
    {
        name: 'PRIORITY_CD', index: 'PRIORITY_CD', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true,
    },{
        name: 'CODE_COMBI', index: 'CODE_COMBI', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true
    },{
        name: 'ACTION', index: 'PRIORITY_CD', width: 200, editable: true, sortable: true, formatter: vieweditdel
    }
]
function vieweditdel(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
    var detail = "<a href=''../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/GetCritCombiMap'" + rowdata.PRIORITY_CD + " > Details</a>";
    var edit = "<a href=''../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/GetCritCombiMap'" + rowdata.PRIORITY_CD + " > Edit</a>";
    var delete = "<a href=''../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/GetCritCombiMap'" + rowdata.PRIORITY_CD + " > Delete</a>";

    return detail+edit+delete;
}
```

Comment: thanks Tony but how to add class on the var detal=...

here is the class name - class="tbl alternate"